# How does ruby on rails map http request to handler function?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to RoR, so please forgive me if this is a stupid thing to ask.

I was looking into `routes.rb` file and found these two lines:

```
get "question/question"
get "question/answer"
```

But there was no mention of the functions they are mapped to.

I tried to look how they are mapped to the functions and in all the tutorials or reference docs I found on net, requests were hashed to function names.

So I was not able to understand the routing in this case. Can someone give names of some files to look into or some documents suitable for beginners which can explain routing clearly, removing the magical part?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the `QuestionsController` and the `question` and `answer` methods.

See [these routing docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#http-verb-constraints) for details on how routing works for these types of paths.

Answer (score 0):

Allow defaults for values when possible.

These lines

```
get question/question
```

and

```
get question/answer
```

means respond to `get` requests that use a url with `question/question` or `question/answer` to be processed by the:

1. `question` controller and the `question` method
2. `question` controller and the `answer` method

You may be more used to working with constructs like:

```
get 'users/change_district/:district_id' => "users#set_district", :as => 'change_district'
```

which allow you to specify which controller (users) and which action (set_district)

If, however, you omit some parts then the router will use what you give and use defaults for anything not specified.

Comment: Yes. I was looking for something like a hash as you mentioned. But it was Rails default. Thanks for answering.